# jQuery.post() dynamically generated data to server returns empty response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post, dynamic-programming

I'm generating a series of variables in a loop (using JS), and I'm assigning them an `.id` and a `.name` based on the current index. At each loop I'm sending a request to the server using `jQuery.post()`method, but the returning response is just an empty variable. 
Here's the code:

**JavaScript**

```
for ( var index = 0; index < 5; index++ ) {

    var myVar = document.createElement('p');

    myVar.id = 'myVarID' + index;

    myVar.name = 'myVarName' + index;


    //Send request to server
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var data = {};

        var i = 'ind';
        var id = myVar.id;
        var name = myVar.name;

        data[id] = name;
        data[i] = index;

        $.post("script.php", data, function(data){

            console.log("Server response:", data);

        });

    });

}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

  $index = $_POST['ind'];

  $myVar = $_POST['myVarID'.$index];

  echo $myVar;

?>
```

**Response:** `Server response: ''`

If I instead set a static index in JS code, getting rid of the loop, so for example:

```
var index = 0;
```

I get the expected result: `Server response: myVarName0`

Why is this happening? And how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

It is working fine removing:

```
$(document).ready()
```

**Working code**

```
for ( var index = 0; index < 5; index++ ) {

    var myVar = document.createElement('p');

    myVar.id = 'myVarID' + index;

    myVar.name = 'myVarName' + index;


    //Send request to server

    var data = {};

    var i = 'ind';
    var id = myVar.id;
    var name = myVar.name;

    data[id] = name;
    data[i] = index;

    $.post("script.php", data, function(data){

        console.log("Server response:", data);

    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the php file is in order. I use this:

```
function doThing(url) {
getRequest(
    url,
    doMe,
    null
    );
    }
     function doMe(responseText) {
    var container = document.getElementById('hahaha');
    container.innerHTML = responseText;
  }
function getRequest(url, success, error) {
var req = false;
try{
    // most browsers
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
    // IE
    try{
        req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        // try an older version
        try{
            req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e){
            return false;
        }
    }
}
if (!req) return false;
if (typeof success != 'function') success = function () {};
if (typeof error!= 'function') error = function () {};
req.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(req .readyState == 4){
        return req.status === 200 ? 
            success(req.responseText) : error(req.status)
        ;
    }
}
var thing = "script.php?" + url;
req.open("GET", thing, true);
req.send(null);
return req;
  }
```

then use it like this:

```
doThing("myVarID="+myVar.id+"&i="+index);
```

also, you will have to change your PHP to something like this:

```
<?php
   $index = $_GET['ind'];

  $myVar = $_GET['myVarID'.$index];

   echo $myVar;

 ?>
```

Obviously this code needs to be edited to suit your own needs

the function doMe is what to do when the webpage responds, in that example I changed the element with the id hahaha to the response text.

This won't win you any prizes but it'll get the job done.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but this is not really an answer to my question. I'm trying to understand why my code is working with static vars and not with dynamic ones.